# Spawn Egg that Hatches Villager with Custom Trades

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to create a villager that trades villager spawn eggs with custom trades. Is this possible in 1.15.2?

Here is my code for creating a villager that trades villager spawn eggs:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:5,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:emerald,Count:10},sell:{id:villager_spawn_egg,Count:1},maxUses:1}]}}
```

However, I'm not certain how to create a spawn egg that will hatch with custom trades. I'm not even sure it can be done. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is just the problem of "spawn egg with mob data in it" and "villager selling items with custom data on it" combined. You should ask about the one that you're having problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:5,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:emerald,Count:10},sell:{id:villager_spawn_egg,Count:1,tag:{EntityTag:{VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:librarian",level:2,type:"minecraft:plains"},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:stick",Count:1b},sell:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b}}]}}}},maxUses:1}]}}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! I appreciate the help!